# Не работает if else c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, if

Если сумма 3 действительных чисел x,y,z <1, то наименьшее из этих чисел заменить полусуммой двух других, в противном случае заменить меньшее из x и  y полусуммой двух оставшихся значений 
[image: gg]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
float x, y, z, s;
cout << "Введите x" << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "Введите y" << endl;
cin >> y;
cout << "Введите z" << endl;
cin >> z;
s = (x + y + z);
if (s < 1)
{
    if ((x < y)&&(y < z)) {
        x = (y + z) / 2;
        cout << "ответ: x=" << x << endl;
    }
}
else if ((s<1)&&(((y < x)&&(x < z)))) {
    y = (x + z) / 2;
    cout <<"ответ: y="<< y << endl;
}
else if ((s<1)&&(((z < x)&&(x < y)))) {
    z = (x + y) / 2;
    cout <<"ответ: z="<< z << endl;
}
else if (x < y) {
    x = (y + z) / 2;
    cout <<"otvetos s x="<< x << endl;
}
else {
    y = (x + z) / 2;
    cout <<"drugoi otvet = "<< y << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

когда я ввожу x=0.3 y=0.1 z=0.2 то в ответе ничего нет

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Опишите, пожалуйста, проблему более подробно.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Все работает...

Comment: когда я ввожу x=0.3 y=0.1 z=0.2 то в ответе ничего нет

Comment: А как можно это починить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работает только эта ветка (при исходных данных s = 0,6, что меньше 1):

```
if (s < 1)
{
    if ((x < y)&&(y < z)) {
        x = (y + z) / 2;
        cout << "ответ: x=" << x << endl;
    }
}
```

На проверке `if ((x < y)&&(y < z))` сразу же получаем false, т.к. на самом деле `x` больше `y`. На этом выполнение программы завершается.

---

Если кажется, что `if` не работает, или работает не так,  как надо, то всегда нужно проверять сами условия, потому что `if` работает всегда. А если "не работает", значит ошибка в условиях.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код по сути состоит из

```
if (s < 1)
{
    if ((x < y)&&(y < z)) {
        x = (y + z) / 2;
        cout << "ответ: x=" << x << endl;
    }
}
...
else if (x < y) {
    x = (y + z) / 2;
    cout <<"otvetos s x="<< x << endl;
}
else {
    y = (x + z) / 2;
    cout <<"drugoi otvet = "<< y << endl;
}
```

Те ветви, где троеточие - работать не будут, так как при `s<1` работает первая ветвь, а во вторую и третью вы попадаете с `s>=1`, так что ваша проверка `if ((s<1)&&...` автоматически дает `false`.